# LISTAGG, change sorting of result with reference to another column

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

I have a table like this:

```
item   Desc
----   ----
CSH    Cash
CHQ    Cheque
CDJ    Cross Department
EPS    EPS
```

and I have SQL like this:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(a.item, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a.item ASC) "item",
LISTAGG(a.Desc, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a.Desc ASC) "Desc"
FROM tableA a;
```

and the result is like:

```
item                 Desc
----                 ----
CDJ,CHQ,CSH,EPS      Cash,Cheque,Cross Department,EPS
```

however, my expected result is to sort 'item' according to the ordering of 'Desc', which means:

'CSH,CHQ,CDJ,EPS'

what can I do about it?

Comment: You are asking for values from a given record to appear spread out across different records in your result set.  While it might be possible to do this, the bigger question is why do want to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution for your problem:

```
SELECT LISTAGG("item", ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "Desc") "item",
LISTAGG("Desc", ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "Desc" ) "Desc"
FROM tableA;
```

**Output:**

```
  item               |     Desc
------------------------------------------------------------
CSH, CHQ, CDJ, EPS   |   Cash, Cheque, Cross Department, EPS
```

Link To the Demo:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/16ed58/10

Answer (score 3):

Just use the same `ORDER BY` in both uses of [`listagg`](https://modern-sql.com/feature/listagg):

```
SELECT LISTAGG(a.item, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a.Desc ASC) "item",
       LISTAGG(a.Desc, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a.Desc ASC) "Desc"
FROM tableA a;
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen CDJ and Cash should not be in the same row, but they are if order by the values themeselves. The expected result CSH and Cash in the first row.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen True, I confused the columns. Fixed now.